# How to Retrieve XML Node Attributes In C#

Tags: xml

how to navigate the XML file and get all a list of nodes in order to access their attributes and count no of nodes in Student tag.

for example :

Can anybody briefy me .how to do ? give any sample code to do so.?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection of XmlNodes from and XmlDocument like this

```
XmlNodeList nodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("MyNodeName");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    // do stuff with each node
}
```

The XmlNode class has an Attributes property which is a collection of attributes.  You can iterate through them and match the attributes you are looking for.