# Read an xml file and retrieve xml node Value using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get the value of attribute(memo) in an xml file using c#,also i want to display the value(wonderful day) in a textbox .Can anyone help?

```
<tree>
  <Product comment=" C# "  memo="Wonderful day" /> 
 </tree>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Retrieve XML Node Attributes In C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653092/how-to-retrieve-xml-node-attributes-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml=@"<tree>
<Product comment="" C# ""  memo=""Wonderful day"" /> 
</tree>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var memo = doc.Document.Descendants("Product").Single().Attribute("memo").Value;
```

Output: `Wonderful day`

Comment: var xml =@"<tree><Product comment="" C# ""  memo=""Wonderful day"" /> 
</tree>";
give error Data at the root level is invalid (xmlexception was unhandled)

Comment: @Karthik, Provided source code works perfectly, without any exception, tested.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)